# How to convert linefeed into literal "\n"

Tags: json, sed, literals, linefeed

I'm having some trouble converting my file to a properly formatted json string. 
Have been fiddling with `sed` for ages now, but it seems to mock me.
Am working on RHEL 6, if that matters.

I'm trying to convert this file (content):

```
Hi there...

foo=bar
tomàto=tomáto
url=http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Into this json string:

```
{"text":"Hi there...\n\nfoo=bar\ntomàto=tomáto\nurl=http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
```

How would I replace the actual line feeds in the literal '\n' character?? This is where I'm utterly stuck!

I've been trying to convert line feeds into ";" first and then back to a literal "\n". Tried loops for each row in the file. Can't make it work...

Some help  is much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `awk` for this :

```
awk -v RS=^$ '{gsub(/\n/,"\\n");sub(/^/,"{\"text\":\"");sub(/\\n$/,"\"}")}1' file
```

**Output**

```
{"text":"Hi there...\n\nfoo=bar\ntomàto=tomáto\nurl=http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
```

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-specific for the multi-char RS.

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Since sed works line by line your sed script doesn't see the line endings and so you can't get it change the line endings without jumping through hoops using arcane language constructs and convoluted logic that hasn't been useful since the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

This will change all newlines in your input file to the string `\n`:

```
$ awk -v ORS='\\n' '1' file
Hi there...\n\nfoo=bar\ntomàto=tomáto\nurl=http://www.stackoverflow.com\n
```

and this will do the rest:

```
$ awk -v ORS='\\n' 'BEGIN{printf "{\"text\":\""} 1; END{printf "\"}\n"}' file
{"text":"Hi there...\n\nfoo=bar\ntomàto=tomáto\nurl=http://www.stackoverflow.com\n"}
```

or this if you have a newline at the end of your input file but don't want it to become a `\n` string in the output:

```
$ awk -v ORS='\\n' '{rec = (NR>1 ? rec ORS : "") $0} END{printf "{\"text\":\"%s\"}\n", rec}' file
{"text":"Hi there...\n\nfoo=bar\ntomàto=tomáto\nurl=http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
```

Comment: Nice. In fact I was looking for a workaround to make my answer, not specific to gawk and you've beat me to it with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/\\n/;ta' file | sed 's/.*/{"text":"&"}/'
```

Output:

```
{"text":"Hi there...\n\nfoo=bar\ntomàto=tomáto\nurl=http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -vRS='\0' '{gsub("\n","\\n"); 
                  print "{\"text\":\"" $0 "\"}"}' file

{"text":"Hi there...\n\nfoo=bar\ntomàto=tomáto\nurl=http://www.stackoverflow.com\n"}
```

Comment: pls note that there is `\n` at the end which is not required as per the expected output. Also by not putting a space in between `-v` and `RS`, the script portability may be restricted.

Comment: Correct, no space between `-v` and the variable name makes it gawk-specific. Use of `\0` for the RS is hit-or-miss too though. It'd probably work for most input files and most gawks but if not to do the job robustly in gawk you'd use `RS='^$'` and in other awks you'd build up the record then process in the END section, `{r=r $0 ORS} END{ do stuff with r}`. We actually don't know from the posted sample input if there's a newline at the end of the input file or not but we can probably assume there is or it's not a POSIX text file and so YMMV with how each tool will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/.*/"text":"&"/;s/\n/\\n/g' file
```

Slurp the file into memory and use pattern matching to manipulate the file to the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple (and elegant ?) solution :) :

```
#!/bin/bash

in=$(perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/' $1)

cat<<EOF
{"text":"$in"} 
EOF
```

#### Usage:

```
./script.sh file.txt
```

#### Output :

```
{"text":"Hi there...\n\nfoo=bar\ntomàto=tomáto\nurl=http://www.stackoverflow.com\n"}
```